# Are deadlocks always a symptom of design flaws or are they an unavoidable occurrence even in well designed systems with high data writes/reads?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

A complete redesign proposal is experiencing deadlocks in its prototype. I am of the opinion that deadlocks are always the symptom of design flaws. I do not want to go into the specifics of our system; I just want to know others'opinion in general situations.
If a system is experiencing deadlocks on volume testing at such an early stage in its development, should the design be reevaluated?

Comment: This is much too broad for a real answer. Deadlocks could be a design flaw but most commonly due to inattention to detail in query/index tuning or inappropriate use of a restrictive transaction isolation level.

Comment: Yes, it is broad, but I think you have put forward an opinion which is meeting my request. You believe that the condition of a deadlock is due to system design issues and not something unavoidable in providing a solution for a system high reads/writes.

Comment: Not necessarily a "design" flaw, but most certainly a bug in the implementation

Comment: Ultimately because SQL Server itself decides which ORDER objects are locked in (due to the execution plan), there is no way to completely negate the chances of a deadlock. This means that it can't be 100% down to design.

Comment: In my opinion, deadlock will occur only when there is already blocking going on. Few scenarios only go for deadlock out of number of blocks. If you have deadlocks that indirectly means you are suffering from blocking already. Check for the blocking also, good design/coding will have minimal blocking/deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

> I am of the opinion that deadlocks are always the symptom of design flaws

With READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT set, and foreign keys supported by indexes, deadlocks should be treated as application bugs.

That's not to say you'll never see a deadlock, or that you won't have to introduce locking hints to serialize access to objects.

But with RCSI, deadlocks should be rare enough that they can be individually diagnosed and remediated, as opposed to using a retry loop or resorting to dirty reads.